# "Order validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

On an eCommerce app I'm building, I am unable to complete a POST request on the app and receive a 500 error. What is bizarre however is that the endpoint works fine on Postman. I don't see how there can be a server error on the app itself but not on the endpoint.

Here is the server code:

```
router.post("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  const newOrder = new Order(req.body);
  try {
    const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Here's the 'verifyToken' middleware:

```
const verifyToken = (req,res,next)=>{
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    if(authHeader){
        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user)=>{
            if(err) res.status(403).json("Token is not correct.");
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json("No token provided. You are not authenticated.");
    }
};
```

Finally, here's the "createOrder" function on the client side:

```
const createOrder = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post("https://ecommerce-store12321.herokuapp.com/api/orders", {
          userId: currentUser._id,
          products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
            productId: item._id,
            quantity: item._quantity,
          })),
          amount: cart.total,
          address: data.billing_details.address,
        }, {
          headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }
        });
        setOrderId(res.data._id);
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
```

Edit:

Here is the Order schema as well:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userId: {type: String, required:true},
        products: [
            {
            productId: {
                type: String
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1,
            }
          },
       ],
       amount: {type: Number, required: true},
       address: { type: Object, required: true},
       status: {type: String, default: "pending"}
    },
    { timestamps: true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema)
```

Comment: You write ``headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }``. Is the bearer token really transported as `token: Bearer ...`, not as `Authorization: Bearer ...`?

Comment: Can you show the Order definition? I would also debug what req.body contains

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I tried using "Authorization" instead but then I received a 401 because the middleware requires the use of "token".

Comment: @wawka The Order schema has been added.

Comment: what is the value of  `currentUser._id` when you call `axios.post`? Check the request in the chrome developer tools if the requestbody actually contains a `userId` and also check on the server side if `req.body` contains a `userId` property.

Comment: And for why a request works in postman but not in the browser: In Postman you proably typed in or pasted the body by hand. In the browser it is filled from a variable's current value. And if something else in your clientside app has gone wrong `currentUser._id` may not have the value you expect it to have ...

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks for the insight. In retrospect, the error message makes perfect sense then. I was passing an undefined userId value in the POST request, which led to the 500 error. Once I properly defined the value, the request worked. Thanks again.